# document.getElementsByClassName("")[0].innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom

need help disturbs my code. Not because reason.
This is my code;

```
<script>
theMovieDb.search.getMovie({"query":"{/literal} {$movie.title} {literal}"}, function(data) {
  var data = JSON.parse(data);
  var Rid = data.results[0];
  var background = Rid.backdrop_path;
var background = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original" + Rid.backdrop_path;
document.getElementsByClassName("real")[0].dataset.original = background;

}, function(error){})
</script>

<img class="base" src="https://trakt.tv/assets/placeholders/thumb/fanart-32d9084d8b6cfeb49a9639b0a8a12af7.png" alt="Fanart"/>
<img class="real" src="https://trakt.tv/assets/placeholders/thumb/fanart-32d9084d8b6cfeb49a9639b0a8a12af7.png" alt="Fanart"/>
```

**I see that so disturbs**

```
<img class="base" alt="Fanart" src="https://trakt.tv/assets/placeholders/thumb/fanart-32d9084d8b6cfeb49a9639b0a8a12af7.png"><img class="real" alt="Fanart" src="https://trakt.tv/assets/placeholders/thumb/fanart-32d9084d8b6cfeb49a9639b0a8a12af7.png"> data-original="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/uHeMMJIZRVjeS2WIFcxBCdCTdmk.jpg"</img>
```

**And the result should be;**

```
<img class="base" src="https://trakt.tv/assets/placeholders/thumb/fanart-32d9084d8b6cfeb49a9639b0a8a12af7.png" alt="Fanart"/><img class="real" data-original="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/uHeMMJIZRVjeS2WIFcxBCdCTdmk.jpg" src="https://trakt.tv/assets/placeholders/thumb/fanart-32d9084d8b6cfeb49a9639b0a8a12af7.png" alt="Fanart"/>
```

Comment: I still do not solve the problem, the code disturbs and because of this the picture is displayed. the solution is not given to me.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would explain why the HTML elements become corrupted. You'll have to show a *complete* example.